# How do I know what is the current file name loaded?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In javascript, is there a way to know what is the currently loaded file name?

E.g. I have file names index.html, history.html, favorites.html. And I'd want to do some conditional logic based on these files loaded.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean what is the current website html page?

Comment: @SheshankS Yes, sort of.

Comment: so like if the site was https://programming.com/programs.html you would want programs.html correct?

Comment: Hmm yes, actually I kinda have a solution that is to have a separate script for each file that just says 'var filename = "{filename.html}";'.. Thinking if there's a better solution. @SheshankS.

Comment: What about `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.pathname`

That will get `page.html` in `https://website.com/page.html`.

It will also get `games/fortnite.html` in `https://gaming.com/games/fortnite.html`, which I assume is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
`var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
 src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
```

`